# CSS - how can I add a vertical scroll in html table

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'm working on a JSP web Project. I have a table that can contains data more than my table height can handle. So I want to add a vertical scroll on my table. How can I do this? I've tried other solution I saw in here but sadly it didn't work out good on me.

What I want is the header should stay/still visible even if I scroll it down. I want the data row only to get scrolled down.

below is my JSP code and CSS

JSP: (I only include the part of where my table is concern)

```
<div id="rightColumn" class="columns">
                <table id="timeTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Balance Time</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach items="${timeProp}" var="_timeProp">
                        <tr>
                            <td><c:out value="${_timeProp.tb_customername}"/></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${_timeProp.tb_time}"/></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${_timeProp.tb_date}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </div>
```

CSS: (same goes here)

```
#rightColumn {
    width: 75%;
    min-height: 388px;
}

.columns {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#timeTable
{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

#timeTable th
{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px;
}

#timeTable td, #timeTable th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#timeTable tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#timeTable tr:hover
{
    background-color: #ddd;
}

table tr.active {background: #ccc;}

#timeTable td
{
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance. Hope you can help me out here.

Comment: What was the other solution you've already tried? Someone may suggest it again. Usually setting an explicit `height` value on a containing element, like `table`, with an `overflow` rule, like `overflow-y: auto`, is enough - but it sounds like you want a fixed table header as well. If that's the case you may need to clarify your question title, and search for fixed header solutions, like https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fixed+table+header .

Comment: You could try separating the table into 2; 1 for all the header parts you need to remain in place on scroll, and 2 for all the data concerned, then declare the `height` and `overflow` on table 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.columns {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: auto; /* add this*/
}
```

[Overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) auto will give you a scroll bar if the content of your div dose not fit.

And if you want the header to stay in place when you scroll you need to give it 
[position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position): `fixed;`

Comment: Hi the vertical scroll appeared and working. But the header disappear as I scroll down. I add the position: fixed; at #timeTable th, tried also in #timeTable but it does not work. Where should I add it?

Comment: @HjReyes You need to add `position: fixed` to the element you want to stay in place, i thought you have another div with the header or something. Maybe edit your code and add your header too.

Comment: I add it in #timeTable th, it worked but there is a problem. The width of it decrease. It sink in. The other header text got cut out. It worked but not as expected. How can I fix that?

Comment: You need to somehow separate the header and content as suggested by @UncaughtTypeError or look at this example i found https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/ it's a bit more complex but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)?

EDIT:

Set your `height` and `overflow-y` for the parent `div`.

Comment: add it on where?

Comment: Try to set the height and overflow for the parent div.

Comment: On your table element